# Probability of a number occurring in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, row, probability

I'm using Matlab and well it's straightforward to find the probability of an element in a matrix, but I a little unsure of how to find probability of an element in a row or column.

e.g this matrix:

```
X = [
    1 2 4 1 8; 
    5 3 6 9 2; 
    6 2 2 3 2
    ];
```

How would I find the probability of "2" occurring in each row and column of this random matrix.

Comment: Is this not more appropriate on math.stackexchange?

Comment: I think I know how to do it mathematically -
1st column) 0
2nd column) 1/3
3rd column) 2/3
4th column) 0
5th column) 2/3

average of all these = 1/3

Not sure how to do this using Matlab.

Comment: Do you just need the frequency of occurrence of a `2` in the given matrix or the acutal probability. For the latter, you need to know what random process has been used to create the matrix and then it's more a mathematical than a Matlab question.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

```
X_unique = unique(X);
p_row = zeros(size(X,1),numel(X_unique));
p_col = zeros(size(X,2),numel(X_unique));

for ii = 1:size(X,1)
    p_row(ii,:) = hist(X(ii,:),X_unique);
    p_row(ii,:) = p_row(ii,:)/sum(p_row(ii,:));
end

for ii = 1:size(X,2)
    p_col(ii,:) = hist(X(:,ii),X_unique);
    p_col(ii,:) = p_col(ii,:)/sum(p_col(ii,:));
end
```

Now, each row of `p_row` contains the probability distribution of the elements of `unique(X)` in the corresponding row of `X` and each row of `p_col` contains the probability distribution of the elements of `unique(X)` in the corresponding column of `X`.

For example, for the given example,

```
X_unique =

     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     8
     9
```

Thus,

```
p_row =

    0.4000    0.2000         0    0.2000         0         0    0.2000         0
         0    0.2000    0.2000         0    0.2000    0.2000         0    0.2000
         0    0.6000    0.2000         0         0    0.2000         0         0

p_col =

    0.3333         0         0         0    0.3333    0.3333         0         0
         0    0.6667    0.3333         0         0         0         0         0
         0    0.3333         0    0.3333         0    0.3333         0         0
    0.3333         0    0.3333         0         0         0         0    0.3333
         0    0.6667         0         0         0         0    0.3333         0
```

Comment: @Deve: `X_unique` is `unique(X)`, the sorted vector of all unique values in X. I've added their values to the answer as per the sample data provided.

Comment: +1. Very complete answer. Probably more than the OP had in mind ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple, not-quite-Matlab-ish solution that works on non-empty bi-dimensional matrices, looking for elements with the value "2", and returning probabilities by column:

```
a = [1 2 4 1 8; 5 3 6 9 2; 6 2 2 3 2];

nrows = size(a,1);
ncols = size(a,2);
pc    = zeros(1, ncols); % Prob. by column

% Iterate trough columns
for k = 1:ncols
        n     = sum(a(:,k) == 2);
        pc(k) = n/nrows;
end;
```

You can adapt it to compute "probabilities" by row, or by other dimensions, or look for other values.